# python: getting substring within element in list

Tags: python

```
row=['alex','liza','hello **world**','blah']
```

i do i get everything in `row[2]` that is between the `**` characters?

Comment: like msw said, dont use a chainsaw, regex is a chainsaw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *could* do it by hand and search for the `*` , but regex work too.

```
print re.search(r'\*\*(.*)\*\*', 'hello **world**').group(1) # prints 'world'
```

You need to know *exactly* what you're looking for with regex, so think about what `**asd**dfe**` and similar edge cases should return.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
print re.findall(r"\*\*(.*)\*\*", row[2])
```

will give you a list of every match in `row[2]` which is between `**`. Fine tune the regex as necessary

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that you don't know which element has the stars, you could use this:

```
row=['alex','liza','hello **world**','blah']
for staritem in (item for item in row if '**' in item):
    print(staritem)
    _,_, staritem = staritem.partition('**')
    staritem,_,_ = staritem.partition('**')
    print(staritem)
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>row[2].strip('*')</s>

Don't use a chainsaw when a knife will do.

Comment: >>> row[2].strip('*')
'hello **world'

Comment: huh? how do you figure out which part is the one between the `**`?